# goOnline doesn't write data in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am printing some custom messages when user clicks on Button, after printing message on `Firebase`, just closing connection by using `database.goOffline()`. Here is my code :

```
private void print() {
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mainRef = database.getReference("messages");
    database.goOnline();

    mainRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            database.goOffline();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            database.goOffline();
        }
    });

    mainRef.child("abcd").setValue("my message " + randomvalue);
}
```

It is working for first time by calling `print()`, but if i am calling it multiple times it just print message for first time, rest of the times it is not doing anything.

Can anyone please provide me solution for that?

Comment: If you call `goOffline()` the Firebase closes the connection to its servers. It will not receive any updates after that. What is this code trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am just trying to put some messages on regular interval and after posting message i am closing database connection, there is nothing else. But when i am calling this method second time, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I recommend against micro-managing your connection like that. Leave it to the Firebase client, it does a pretty good job of this already. If you insist on staying this course, maybe you can see what's going on by enabling [debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i will take a look into that.